# Gensim word2vec finding nearest words given a word

Tags: gensim, word2vec

How can I find the N-nearest words given a word using gensim's word2vec implementation. What is the API for that? I am referring to skip grams here. Maybe I missed something, I read all about finding similar words, finding the odd one out and so on...

In DL4j I have this method called `wordsNearest(String A, int n) which gives me the n-nearest words to A`. What is the equivalent of this in Gensim?

Comment: [most_similar](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html)

Comment: Thanks Radim. Great to get an answer from the creator himself. Well what I meant was say the input to the model is wi, and the output could be wi−1,wi−2,wi+1,wi+2. So the task here is predicting the context given a word i.e. Skip Gram model, so I just wanted to know what is the API that can give me wi−1,wi−2,wi+1,wi+2 given wi.

Comment: @Radim:I might be wrong. For example given a word earthquake, most_similar would give me Richter scale, tremor etc. however what I need is something like predicting  the probability of the context so I can get a context like "Japan was earthquake epicenter" so the API could give me wi-2 = Japan wi-1=was and wi+1=epicenter. Now again there can be several contexts and I will just get the probabilities of occurrence of wi-1,wi-2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really old, but anyway:
I'm still not entirely sure how hierarchical softmax and negative sampling work, but in principle you should be able to take a vector from the input matrix, multiply it by vectors in the output matrix, and choose the highest value.

```
w1_vec = model[word] #Get the vector for the word you're interested in.
# Loop over the words in the output matrix and take dot products.
for idx, w2_vec in enumerate(model.syn1neg):
    print(idx, model.index2word[idx], np.exp(np.dot(w1_vec, w2_vec)))
```

Then choose the highest values from the output. Use syn1neg / syn1 depending on negative sampling / hierarchical softmax. I've used this technique on a few sample texts and the results are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [most_similar](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.most_similar):

```
model.most_similar(positive=['woman'])
```